# Make the Height of Masonry Boxes Fixed size

Tags: wordpress, themes, height, jquery-masonry, fluid

the website is the following: http://smokingdesigners.com

I have a problem with the masonry view of my pages.

I have recently changed my theme to a new one and my old theme used to add automatically  on every article the "more" tag in order to crop my articles to fit to their masonry, So I have never actually added the "more" tag in more than 1200 articles.

My new theme is cropping the articles weird and that causes my page to be messed up because one box has height lets say 600 (including the picture) and the other 450 and it doesn't look good. (link with problem http://smokingdesigners.com/page/10/ )

Is there a way to make a fixed size boxes with heigh 575 lets say?

here is my masonry theme code..

```
  $def_teaser_width = ( $dtw = get_option('wpb_post_teaser_width') ) ? $dtw : 'two-third';

if ( get_option('wpb_blog_layout') == __("Masonry", "wpb") ) {
    $gallery_style = 'masonry';
} else {
    $gallery_style = 'fluid';
}

if ( $_GET['style'] == 'masonry' ) {
    $gallery_style = 'masonry';
} else if ( $_GET['style'] == 'fluid' ) {
    $gallery_style = 'fluid';
}

$holder_class = ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' ) ? 'masonry_blocks' : 'float_blocks';

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="float_blocks_container">
    <div class="blog_teasers <?php echo $holder_class; ?>">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : 
        $teasers_count = 0;
        ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $teasers_count++;
        $teaser_width = ( $tw = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_teaser_width", true) ) ? $tw : $def_teaser_width;
        $teaser_width = ( $teaser_width == 'default' ) ? $def_teaser_width : $teaser_width;
        //$teaser_width = ($teaser_w = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_teaser_width", true)) ? ' '.$teaser_w : ' one-half';
        if ( $teaser_width == 'one-third' || ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' && $teaser_width == 'one-half' )) {
            $th_w = 320;
            $th_h = 180;
        }
        else if ( $teaser_width == 'one-half' ) {
            $th_w = 495;
            $th_h = 278;
        }
        else if ( $teaser_width == 'two-third' || ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' && $teaser_width == 'full-width' ) ) {
            $th_w = 670;
            $th_h = 377;
        }
        else if ( $teaser_width == 'full-width' ) {
            $th_w = 1020;
            $th_h = 574;
        }

        $content_type = (get_option('wpb_full_content') == 'true') ? ' full_content_in_blog' : '';
        $has_thumbnail = '';
        if (has_post_thumbnail() == false) { $has_thumbnail = ' no_thumbnail'; }
        ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("post_teaser float_block ".$teaser_width.$has_thumbnail.$content_type); ?>>
            <?php
            $video_w = $th_w;
            $video_h = $th_h;
            $p_video = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_p_video", true);

            $youtube = strpos($p_video, 'youtube.com');
            $vimeo = strpos($p_video, 'vimeo');
            if ( $youtube || $vimeo ) : ?>
            <div class="p_video">
            <?php
                if ( $youtube ) {
                    preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $p_video, $matches);
                    echo '<iframe width="'.$video_w.'" height="'.$video_h.'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                }
                else if ( $vimeo ) {
                    preg_match('#vimeo.com/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)?#s', $p_video, $matches);
                    echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$matches[1].'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="'.$video_w.'" height="'.$video_h.'" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                }
            ?>
            </d
```

HERE IS FUNCTIONS.PHP FILE.

```
<?php 
/*
    wpb_category_filter
    wpb_get_video_or_thumbnail
    wpb_blog_pagination - previous/next page navigation
    wpb_tags - return array with tags attached to post from specific vocab.
    wpb_posted_under - return array with taxonomy object from specific vocab.
    siteAttachedImages - 
    metaAttachedImages

    wpb_login_head - changes logo in the WP login screen
    wpb_resize - resize image to the specific dimensions
    curPageURL - return current page url
*/

/* Category filter
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('wpb_category_filter')) {
function wpb_category_filter ( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category', 'posts' => NULL, 'echo' => true, 'filter_text' => __('Filter:', 'wpb_framework') );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = (object) $args;

    if ( $args->posts == NULL) {
        global $wp_query;
        $args->posts = $wp_query->posts;
    }

    $categories_slugs_array = array();
    $categories_names_array = array();
    foreach ($args->posts as $p) {
        $post_categories_array = wpb_get_post_categories(array('taxonomy' => $args->taxonomy, 'pid' => $p->ID));
        if ( $post_categories_array ) {
            $categories_slugs_array[$p->ID] = array();
            $categories_names_array[$p->ID] = array();
            if ( $post_categories_array['slug'] != NULL ) {
                $categories_slugs_array[$p->ID] = array_unique( array_merge($post_categories_array['slug'], $categories_slugs_array[$p->ID]) );
                $categories_names_array[$p->ID] = array_unique( array_merge($post_categories_array['name'], $categories_names_array[$p->ID]) );
            }
        }
    }

    $all_cats = array(); $all_slugs = array();

    foreach ( $categories_names_array as $c ) { $all_cats = array_unique( array_merge( $all_cats, $c ) ); }
    foreach ( $categories_slugs_array as $c ) { $all_slugs = array_unique( array_merge( $all_slugs, $c ) ); }

    $filter = '';
    if ( count($all_cats) > 0 ) :
        $filter .= '<ul class="wpb_sort">';
        $filter .=  '<li class="wpb_all_cats"><span>'.$args->filter_text.'</span> <a class="wpb_sortable_current" href="#">'. __("All", "wpb_framework") .'</a></li>';          
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($all_cats); $i++) {
            $filter .= '<li><a class="wpb_sortable_cats" href="#" data-value="sortable-'.$all_slugs[$i].'">'.$all_cats[$i].'</a></li>';
        }
        $filter .= '</ul>';
        unset($i);
    endif;

    return array('links' => $filter, 'categories_slugs_array' => $categories_slugs_array);
    /*if ( $args->echo ) {
        echo $filter;
    } else {
        return $filter;
    }*/
}
}

/* Get video or thumbnail
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('wpb_get_video_or_thumbnail')) {
function wpb_get_video_or_thumbnail( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'pid' => NULL, 'width' => 300, 'height' => 'proportional', 'force_image' => false, 'video_height' => 250, 'img_class' => NULL, 'echo' => true, 'before' => '', 'after' => '' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = (object) $args;

    if ($args->pid == NULL) {
        global $post;
        $pid = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $pid = $args->pid;
    }

    $has_thumbnail = '';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($pid) == false ) { $has_thumbnail = ' no_thumbnail'; }

    $video_w = $args->width;
    $video_h = $args->video_height;
    $p_video = get_post_meta($pid, "_p_video", true);

    $hide_image = get_post_meta($pid, "_hide_image", true);

    $youtube = strpos($p_video, 'youtube.com');
    $vimeo = strpos($p_video, 'vimeo');
    if ( ($youtube || $vimeo) && !$args->force_image ) : ?>
    <div class="p_video">
    <?php
        if ( $youtube ) {
            preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $p_video, $matches);
            echo $args->before.'<iframe width="'.$video_w.'" height="'.$video_h.'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'.$args->after;
        }
        else if ( $vimeo ) {
            preg_match('#vimeo.com/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)?#s', $p_video, $matches);
            echo $args->before.'<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$matches[1].'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="'.$video_w.'" height="'.$video_h.'" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>'.$args->after;
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( ($has_thumbnail == '' && $hide_image != 'no' && $youtube == false && $vimeo == false)
            || $hide_image != 'no' && $args->force_image == true
    ) :
    $th_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($pid);
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $th_id, 'full' );
    if ( $args->height == 'proportional' ) {
        $th_h = round($video_w/$image_src[1] * $image_src[2]);
    } else {
        $th_h = $args->height;
    }

    $image = wpb_resize( $th_id, '', $video_w, $th_h, true );
    $html  = $args->before . '<img ';
    $html .= ( $args->img_class ) ? ' class="'. $args->img_class .'"' : '';
    $html .= ' src="'. $image['url'] .'" alt="" />'. $args->after;
    if ($image['url'] && $args->echo) :
        echo $html;
    else:
        return $html;
    endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php
}
}


/* Outputs next/previous links paginator
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('wpb_next_prev_pagination')) {
function wpb_next_prev_pagination( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'next_txt' => '', 'prev_txt' => '', 'extra_class' => '' );   
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = (object) $args;

    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
    if ($args->next_txt == '') $args->next_txt = '&lt; ' . __('Previous posts', 'wpb_framework');
    if ($args->prev_txt == '') $args->prev_txt = __('Next posts', 'wpb_framework') . ' &gt;';
    if ($args->extra_class != '') $args->extra_class = ' ' . $args->extra_class;
    ?>
    <div class="wpb_paginator<?php echo $args->extra_class; ?>">
        <?php next_posts_link($args->next_txt); previous_posts_link($args->prev_txt); ?><?php //previous == Se tidligere indlæg ?>
    </div>
<?php
    endif;
}
}

/* Paged paginator
---------------------------------------------------------- */
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'previous_posts_link_css' ); 
function previous_posts_link_css($content) {
    return 'class="controls left_control"';
}
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'next_posts_link_css' ); 
function next_posts_link_css($content) {
    return 'class="right_control"';
}

if ( !function_exists('wpb_pagination') ) {
//Thanks Kriesi for the nice paginator
function wpb_pagination( $pages = '', $range = 10 ) {  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     //global $paged;
     $paged = get_query_var('paged');
     if ( empty($paged) ) $paged = 1;

     if ( $pages == '' ) {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if ( !$pages ) {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if ( 1 != $pages ) {         
         echo "<div class='wp-pagenavi'>";         
         //if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         //if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ( $i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++ ) {
             if ( 1 != $pages && ( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                 echo ( $paged == $i ) ? "<span class='current'>". $i ."</span>" : "<a href='". get_pagenum_link($i) ."' class='inactive' >". $i ."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) previous_posts_link('&larr;');  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) next_posts_link('&rarr;');

         //if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         //if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";

         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
}

/* Receives taxonomy name as argument and returns array
   with tags objects
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if ( !function_exists('wpb_tags') ) {
function wpb_tags( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'pid' => NULL, 'tag_vocab' => '', 'echo' => true, 'before' => '', 'separator' => '', 'after' => '' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = (object) $args;

    if ($args->pid == NULL) {
        global $post;
        $pid = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $pid = $args->pid;
    }

    if ($args->tag_vocab != '') {
        $output = get_the_term_list($pid, $args->tag_vocab, $args->before, $args->separator, $args->after);
    } else {
        $c_arr = array();
        $tags_arr = get_the_tags();
        if ($tags_arr) {
            foreach($tags_arr as $tag) {
                $c_arr[] = $args->before.'<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="">' . $tag->name . '</a>'.$args->after;
            } 
            $output = implode($args->separator, $c_arr);
        }
    }

    if ($output and $args->echo) {
        echo $output;
    } else if ($output) {
        return $output;
    }
}
}


/* 
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('wpb_get_post_category_names')) {
function wpb_get_post_categories( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => '', 'pid' => NULL, 'echo' => TRUE );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = (object) $args;

    if ( $args->pid == NULL ) {
        global $post;
        $args->pid = $post->ID;
    }

    if ( $args->taxonomy != '' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($args->pid, $args->taxonomy);
    }
    if ( $terms ) {
        $term_output = array();
        $names = array();
        $slugs = array();

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $names[] = $term->name;
            $slugs[] = $term->slug;
        }
        $term_output['name'] = array_unique($names);
        $term_output['slug'] = array_unique($slugs);

        return $term_output;
    }
}
}

/* Receives taxonomy name as argument and returns array
   with taxonomy objects
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('wpb_posted_under')) {
function wpb_posted_under( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => '', 'pid' => NULL, 'echo' => TRUE, 'separator' => ', ', 'link' => TRUE );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args = (object) $args;

    if ($args->pid == NULL) {
        global $post;
        $args->pid = $post->ID;
    }

    if ($args->taxonomy != '') {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($args->pid, $args->taxonomy);
    }
    else {
        $terms = array();
        foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
            //get_category_link($category->cat_ID)
            //$category->cat_name
            $terms[] = $category;
        }
    }
    if ($terms) {
        $term_output = '';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            //$term_output[] = '<a href="'.get_category_link($term->term_id).'" title="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            if ($args->link) {
                $term_output[] = '<a href="'.get_term_link($term).'" title="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            }
            else {
                $term_output[] = $term->name;
            }

        }
        $term_output = implode($args->separator, $term_output);
        if ($args->echo) {
            echo $term_output;
        }
        else {
            return $term_output;
        }
    }
}
}


/* Helper function which returs list of site attached images,
   and if image is attached to the current post it adds class
   'added'
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('siteAttachedImages')) {
function siteAttachedImages($att_ids = array()) {
    $output = '';

    global $wpdb;
    $media_images = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' order by ID desc");
    foreach($media_images as $image_post) {
        $thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_post->ID, 'thumbnail');
        $thumb_src = $thumb_src[0];

        $class = (in_array($image_post->ID, $att_ids)) ? ' class="added"' : '';

        if ($thumb_src) {
            $output .= '<li'.$class.'>
                            <img rel="'.$image_post->ID.'" src="'. $thumb_src .'" alt="'. $img_details[0] .'" />
                            <span class="img-added">'. __('Added', 'wpb_framework') .'</span>
                        </li>';
        }
    }

    if ($output != '') {
        $output = '<ul class="gallery_widget_img_select">' . $output . '</ul>';
    }
    return $output;
}
}

/* Helper function. Outputs attached images to the post
   in custom meta section.
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('metaAttachedImages')) {
function metaAttachedImages($att_ids = array()) {
    $output = '';

    foreach ($att_ids as $img_id) {
        $thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'thumbnail');
        $thumb_src = $thumb_src[0];

        if ($thumb_src) {
            $output .= '<li class="added">
                        <img rel="'.$img_id.'" src="'. $thumb_src .'" alt="" />
                        <span class="img-added">'. __('Added', 'wpb_framework') .'</span>
                    </li>';
        }

    }

    return $output;
}
}


function getTopLevelCategories() {
    $topCat = array();
    $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category->parent == 0) {
            $topCat[] = $category->name;
        }
    }
    return $topCat;
}




/* Goldmines from internet
---------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Change Wordpress logo on login screen
---------------------------------------------------------- */
if (!function_exists('wpb_login_head')) {
add_action("login_head", "wpb_login_head");
function wpb_login_head() {
    echo "
    <style>
    body.login #login h1 a {
        background: url('".get_bloginfo('template_url')."/images/logotype.png') no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    }
    </style>
    ";
}
}


/*
 * Resize images dynamically using wp built in functions
 * Victor Teixeira
 *
 * php 5.2+
 *
 * Exemplo de uso:
 * 
 * <?php 
 * $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
 * $image = vt_resize( $thumb, '', 140, 110, true );
 * ?>
 * <img src="<?php echo $image[url]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[width]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[height]; ?>" />
 *
 * @param int $attach_id
 * @param string $img_url
 * @param int $width
 * @param int $height
 * @param bool $crop
 * @return array
 */
if (!function_exists('wpb_resize')) {
function wpb_resize( $attach_id = null, $img_url = null, $width, $height, $crop = false ) {

    // this is an attachment, so we have the ID
    if ( $attach_id ) {

        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id, 'full' );
        $file_path = get_attached_file( $attach_id );

    // this is not an attachment, let's use the image url
    } else if ( $img_url ) {

        $file_path = parse_url( $img_url );
        $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file_path['path'];

        //$file_path = ltrim( $file_path['path'], '/' );
        //$file_path = rtrim( ABSPATH, '/' ).$file_path['path'];

        $orig_size = getimagesize( $file_path );

        $image_src[0] = $img_url;
        $image_src[1] = $orig_size[0];
        $image_src[2] = $orig_size[1];
    }

    $file_info = pathinfo( $file_path );
    $extension = '.'. $file_info['extension'];

    // the image path without the extension
    $no_ext_path = $file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'];

    $cropped_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$width.'x'.$height.$extension;

    // checking if the file size is larger than the target size
    // if it is smaller or the same size, stop right here and return
    if ( $image_src[1] > $width || $image_src[2] > $height ) {

        // the file is larger, check if the resized version already exists (for $crop = true but will also work for $crop = false if the sizes match)
        if ( file_exists( $cropped_img_path ) ) {

            $cropped_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $cropped_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

            $vt_image = array (
                'url' => $cropped_img_url,
                'width' => $width,
                'height' => $height
            );

            return $vt_image;
        }

        // $crop = false
        if ( $crop == false ) {

            // calculate the size proportionaly
            $proportional_size = wp_constrain_dimensions( $image_src[1], $image_src[2], $width, $height );
            $resized_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$proportional_size[0].'x'.$proportional_size[1].$extension;            

            // checking if the file already exists
            if ( file_exists( $resized_img_path ) ) {

                $resized_img_url = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $resized_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

                $vt_image = array (
                    'url' => $resized_img_url,
                    'width' => $proportional_size[0],
                    'height' => $proportional_size[1]
                );

                return $vt_image;
            }
        }

        // no cache files - let's finally resize it
        $new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );
        if ( is_string($new_img_path) == false ) { return ''; }
        $new_img_size = getimagesize( $new_img_path );
        $new_img = str_replace( basename( $image_src[0] ), basename( $new_img_path ), $image_src[0] );

        // resized output
        $vt_image = array (
            'url' => $new_img,
            'width' => $new_img_size[0],
            'height' => $new_img_size[1]
        );

        return $vt_image;
    }

    // default output - without resizing
    $vt_image = array (
        'url' => $image_src[0],
        'width' => $image_src[1],
        'height' => $image_src[2]
    );

    return $vt_image;
}
}

/* Returns current page url
---------------------------------------------------------- */
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") { $pageURL .= "s"; }

    $pageURL .= "://";

    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

---AND FINALLY THE MASONRY FLUID THEME FILE---

```
<?php
$def_teaser_width = ( $dtw = get_option('wpb_post_teaser_width') ) ? $dtw : 'two-third';

if ( get_option('wpb_blog_layout') == __("Masonry", "wpb") ) {
    $gallery_style = 'masonry';
} else {
    $gallery_style = 'fluid';
}

if ( $_GET['style'] == 'masonry' ) {
    $gallery_style = 'masonry';
} else if ( $_GET['style'] == 'fluid' ) {
    $gallery_style = 'fluid';
}

$holder_class = ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' ) ? 'masonry_blocks' : 'float_blocks';

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="float_blocks_container">
    <div class="blog_teasers <?php echo $holder_class; ?>">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : 
        $teasers_count = 0;
        ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
        $teasers_count++;
        $teaser_width = ( $tw = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_teaser_width", true) ) ? $tw : $def_teaser_width;
        $teaser_width = ( $teaser_width == 'default' ) ? $def_teaser_width : $teaser_width;
        //$teaser_width = ($teaser_w = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_teaser_width", true)) ? ' '.$teaser_w : ' one-half';
        if ( $teaser_width == 'one-third' || ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' && $teaser_width == 'one-half' )) {
            $th_w = 320;
            $th_h = 180;
        }
        else if ( $teaser_width == 'one-half' ) {
            $th_w = 495;
            $th_h = 278;
        }
        else if ( $teaser_width == 'two-third' || ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' && $teaser_width == 'full-width' ) ) {
            $th_w = 670;
            $th_h = 377;
        }
        else if ( $teaser_width == 'full-width' ) {
            $th_w = 1020;
            $th_h = 574;
        }

        $content_type = (get_option('wpb_full_content') == 'true') ? ' full_content_in_blog' : '';
        $has_thumbnail = '';
        if (has_post_thumbnail() == false) { $has_thumbnail = ' no_thumbnail'; }
        ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("post_teaser float_block ".$teaser_width.$has_thumbnail.$content_type); ?>>
            <?php
            $video_w = $th_w;
            $video_h = $th_h;
            $p_video = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_p_video", true);

            $youtube = strpos($p_video, 'youtube.com');
            $vimeo = strpos($p_video, 'vimeo');
            if ( $youtube || $vimeo ) : ?>
            <div class="p_video">
            <?php
                if ( $youtube ) {
                    preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $p_video, $matches);
                    echo '<iframe width="'.$video_w.'" height="'.$video_h.'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                }
                else if ( $vimeo ) {
                    preg_match('#vimeo.com/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)?#s', $p_video, $matches);
                    echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$matches[1].'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="'.$video_w.'" height="'.$video_h.'" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                }
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $has_thumbnail == '' && $youtube == false && $vimeo == false) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php
            $th_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $th_id, 'full' );
            $th_h = 220;

            $image = wpb_resize( $th_id, '', $th_w, $th_h, true );
            if ($image['url']) : ?>
            <img class="post_teaser_img" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="teaser_content">
                <h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <div class="post_info">
                    <span class="light"><?php _e("Posted by", "wpb"); ?></span> <?php the_author(); ?> <span class="light"><?php _e("in", "wpb"); ?></span> <?php wpb_posted_under(); ?> <span class="date"><span class="light"><?php _e("on ", "wpb"); ?></span><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></span>
                </div>

                <?php
                if ($content_type == ' full_content_in_blog') {
                    the_content('');
                } else {
                    the_excerpt('');
                }
                ?>
            </div> <!-- end .teaser_content -->

            <div class="teaser_meta">
                <a class="read_more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e("Read more...", "wpb"); ?></a>
                <span class="comment_balloon"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'wpb' ), __( '1 Comment', 'wpb' ), __( '% Comments', 'wpb' ) ); ?></span>

                <div class="social_buttons">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[vc_facebook type="button_count" url="'.get_permalink().'"]'); ?>
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[vc_tweetmeme]'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="wpb_clear"></div>
            </div> <!-- end .teaser_ment -->
        </div> <!-- end .post_teaser -->
        <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
        <?php if ( $teasers_count > 1 && $gallery_style != 'masonry') : ?>
        <a id="float_prev" class="tooltip" title="<?php _e("Previous post", "wpb"); ?>"></a>
        <a id="float_next" class="tooltip" title="<?php _e("Next post", "wpb"); ?>"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $gallery_style != 'masonry' ) { wpb_pagination(); } ?>

        <div class="wpb_clear"></div>
    </div> <!-- end main_content -->
    <?php
    if ( $gallery_style == 'masonry' ) {
        echo '<div class="masonry_paginator">';
        wpb_pagination();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wpb_clear"></div>
</div> <!-- end container_12 -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by making sure all the excerpts, as the auto-generated short intro-texts are called, are the same length. Also, there is HTML markup in these excerpts, which is not a good idea if you want consistent use of space. So, here we go.

In your theme's `functions.php` you should add the following:

```php
function my_new_excerpt_length($length) {
  return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'my_new_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Here, `my_new_excerpt_length` is the custom name of your function. The `20` is the amount of words you would like your excerpt to be. You can tweak these values, of course. Just experiment until it fits your needs.

**Note:** It might be that the changes are not showing up for you on that specific page. Please post the complete template, so I can take a look at what's happening further down the page.

Comment: OK so I tried your code and the result is good but the titles now and some of the text goes beyond the lines. like this photo: http://cl.ly/2r3F3T2E3g0v323b3B0v can u also give me a code for the titles? but if a title is too long to add like three dots … ? Best Regards, Evan